# Merge between columns from the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I've the following dataframe:

```
id;name;parent_of
1;John;3
2;Rachel;3
3;Peter;
```

Where the column "parent_of" is the id of the parent id. What I want to get the is the name instead of the id on the column "parent_of".
Basically I want to get this:

```
  id;name;parent_of
    1;John;Peter
    2;Rachel;Peter
    3;Peter;
```

I already wrote a solution but is not the more effective way:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'id': [1, 2, 3], 'name': ['John', 'Rachel', 'Peter'], 'parent_of': [3,3,'']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df_tmp  = df[['id', 'name']]
df = pd.merge(df, df_tmp, left_on='parent_of', right_on='id', how='left').drop('parent_of', axis=1).drop('id_y', axis=1)
df=df.rename(columns={"name_x": "name", "name_y": "parent_of"})
print(df)
```

Do you have any better solution to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with `map`

```
df['parent_of']=df.parent_of.map(df.set_index('id')['name'])
df
Out[514]: 
   id    name parent_of
0   1    John     Peter
1   2  Rachel     Peter
2   3   Peter       NaN
```